# Linked Queue class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have defined a class Queue using a homemade class Node. I think it's working as intended but I'm unsure if the code nonetheless is correct. Mostly I'm concerned about assigning both self.first and self.last to p (a new node) when the queue is empty. My reasoning is that since p will be the only node, it will be both the first and the last node but this may not be the Pythonic way to think. Is my code below sensible?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=0
        self.next=None
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first=None
        self.last=None
    def isempty(self):
        return self.first==None
    def put(self,x):
        p=Node()
        p.value=x
        if self.first==None:
            self.first=p
            self.last=p
        else:
            self.last.next=p
            self.last=p
    def get(self):
     if self.isempty():
        print('Queue is empty!')
     else:
        x=self.first.value
        self.first=self.first.next
        return x
```

Comment: When you are assigning first and last node as the same node, you are basically making it a circular queue.

Comment: @Muctadir That is what I was afraid of. What should I assign the last node to?

Comment: And muctadir, that not true. circular linked like would be `self.first.next = self.first`. It's perfectly fine to have both pointers on the same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's a problem here, you will loose the Head pointer after the first call to get, or is it on purpose?

```
def get(self):
     try:
        x=self.first.value
        self.first=self.first.next
        return x
     except AttributeError:
        print('Empty queue!')
```

Additionally, instead of catching AttributeError why don't you use the self.isempty() method.

About self.last: It does not seem like you need it at all.

I would modify Node as follows:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, val=0):
    self.value= val
    self.next = None
```

So that you can write:

```
def put(self,x):
    p = Node(x)
```

Below could be shortened a bit:
From:

```
    if self.first==None:
        self.first=p
        self.last=p
    else:
        self.last.next=p
        self.last=p
```

To:

```
    if self.first==None:
        self.first=p
    else:
        self.last.next=p
    self.last=p
```

It's a bit strange to me to use a Linked list as a Queue, but hey, why not :)

Note about code styling:
Use more spaces, and try to follow https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
You can run flake8 or pylint on you code to learn by practice (instead of reading the PEP ;-) )

Edit:

The new get is fine. You could avoid the `else` like that. As a rule of thumb the less conditional statement / scope the better:

```
 if self.isempty():
    print('Queue is empty!')
    return None

 x = self.first.value
 self.first = self.first.next
 return x
```

For your question about `val=0`, it's called a default parameter, so if you call `Node()` without specifying a `val` it will be `0` anyway.

```
n = Node()
print(n.val)
>> 0
n = Node(42)
print(n.val)
>> 42
```

Comment: What is "Head pointer"? I just started learning about stacks/queues and that term has not been brought up yet. 

I edited in a change to the get-method. Please tell me if it is better. 

Could you tell me what it means to put val=0 as an argument to the __init__-method?

Comment: No worries its just jargon. The first and last elements of a list are often referred to as head and tail, respectively.

Comment: I hit enter prematurely. I added some more stuff to my comment!

Comment: I updated my answer according to your questions.